# How do I use a card formatted as exfat by my Canon 6D in Linux?

Tags: sdcard, canon-6d, linux, import, filesystems

I hope it's not too OS specific/non-photography techy for this forum but I wonder if other 6D users have this problem and I just want to get my workflow improved:

I formatted a fresh Sandisk Extreme 64GB UHS-I card in my new Canon 6d.
When trying to import the photos from my card under Linux with my all-time favorite photomanagement app digikam, I noticed it didn't get automounted and the format was infact exFAT (although I read the 6D only formats cards >=256GB in exFAT):

```
mount: /dev/sdc1: more filesystems detected. This should not happen,
   use -t <type> to explicitly specify the filesystem type or
   use wipefs(8) to clean up the device.
```

So I mounted it by hand, which worked fine, but was cumbersome.
I also noticed some buffer I/O errors in my demsg log:
    Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 16, async page read

So I fired up exfatfsck on the device, which gave me no errors:

```
# exfatfsck /dev/sdc1
exfatfsck 1.1.0
Checking file system on /dev/sdc1.
File system version           1.0
Sector size                 512 bytes
Cluster size                128 KB
Volume size                  59 GB
Used space                   11 GB
Available space              49 GB
Totally 4 directories and 2642 files.
File system checking finished. No errors found.
```

Tried to inspect the card in partitionmanager but it didn't detect the filesystem type, either.

I wonder what's wrong with my card and how I can get my 6D to work better with my system, don't want to mount by hand every time (udev rules don't work since the card doesn't have a label and no UUID).

Answer (score 4):

Just solved the issue by chance - I used `exfatlabel` to name my card and voilá it was auto-detected and works fine under Linux and in my 6d:)

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you have to use a specific label, or just any label at all?

Comment: I doubt that "canon6d" is a special name;) So any name should do, it just needs a label. Maybe exfatlabel corrects some other structural bogusity and cleans up the filesystem. Did you try with just exfatfsck?